# In SQL how do I select rows from one table based on two sets of conditions?

Tags: sqlite

I have a table that contains multiple comparisons.  I'd like to return rows that pass one set of conditions but not another set of conditions for each `id`:

```
id     sample1    sample2    sig
A1     blue       red        yes
A1     blue       green      yes
A1     green      red        no
A2     blue       red        yes
A2     blue       green      no
A2     green      red        yes
```

I would like to return the rows for each `id` where `sig = "yes"` for `blue` versus `red` unless `sig = "yes"` for `green` versus `red`.

Or using simple language, "For each value of "id" where `sample1 = "blue"` and `sample2 = "red"` and `sig = "yes"`, only return the row if the `green` versus `red` equals `no`

So A1 would return `A1     blue       red        yes` and A2 wouldn't return anything because although blue versus red = yes, green versus red = yes.

I imagine I nest two queries where both queries pass and then I do some kind of join, but I haven't been able to crack it.

Comment: Does "versus" have something to do with the two color columns in the table?  I also removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag on ly with the database you are really using.

Comment: Your two descriptions of the criteria are not equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where sample1 = 'blue' and sample2 = 'red' and sig = 'yes' and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.id = t.id and
                    t2.sample1 = 'green' and sample2 = 'red' and sig = 'no'
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NOT IN

```
    SELECT Id FROM MyTable WHERE sig = 'yes' 
AND Sample1 = 'blue' AND sample2 = 'red' AND 
Id NOT IN 
(select Id FROM MyTable where sig='yes' and sample1 = 'green' and sample2 = 'red')
```

Comment: `where id not in` should be `and id not in`

Comment: You're missing `FROM tablename`

Comment: You need parentheses around the subquery. You're missing `FROM` in the subquery.

Comment: And take the plain text out of the indented code block.

Answer (score 0):

Use a self-join

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable AS t1
JOIN yourTable AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.sample1 = 'blue' and t1.sample2 = 'red' AND t1.sig = 'yes'
AND t2.sample1 = 'green' AND t2.sample2 = 'red' AND t2.sig = 'no'
```